# How to authenticate GCP AI Platform Predictions using HTTP requests

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, httprequest, google-cloud-iam, google-ai-platform

I have deployed a model to AI Platform Predictions successfully by following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/xebia-france/how-to-deploy-your-own-ml-model-to-gcp-in-5-simple-steps-bf2b5898c1ab#de11). Now, I want to make predictions with this model via HTTP requests.

As suggested by @Ismail, I followed [Method: projects.predict](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/predict#http-request) documentation.

I'm sending a POST request to `https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/models/${MODEL_NAME}:predict` with the following body:

```
{
  "instances": [
    [51.0, 17.0, 6.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
  ]
}
```

The numbers are the model's input.

I receive the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

I sent the POST request using the RestMan chrome extension. I would like to be able to get a prediction with RestMan.

My question is: how can I authenticate my HTTP POST request? Should I send some information in the request's header?

Comment: If you need more details, make sure to update your question with your use case. I will update my answer below accordingly

Comment: @Ismail just updated it. Thanks!

Comment: Your 401 error means that you'd need to authenticate before running the request https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/faq#why_does_my_request_have_invalid_authentication_credentials

Comment: Where are you running the request? Cloud Shell, your local terminal or client library. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

Comment: @Ismail I'm running my request with RestMan chrome extension.

Comment: You should follow this https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/chrome-extension

Comment: @Ismail hmm it doesn't seem right. This tutorial is for signing in users from a chrome extension. What I want to do is just to get AI Platform Predictions, which doesn't require any signing in. I have to authenticate in a similar way that I would if I was using the sdk.

Comment: So, which authentication method are you trying/preferring to follow here?

Comment: @Ismail I guess it's some token that I have to pass in the HEADER of the request

Comment: Here's an example on how https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/tut_oauth/#create_call, by providing one of GCP's oauth strategies https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#strategies

Answer (score 1):

When you access to Google API, you need to add an access token in your header. With the CLI you can generate it like this:

```
gcloud auth print-access-token
```

*Of course, the current credential needs to be authorized on the AI platform prediction service.*

If you perform a curl, you can do this on linux (and cloud shell)

```
curl -X POST -d @bodyfile.json -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
  https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/models/${MODEL_NAME}:predic
```

---

If you use RestMan, I'm not sure it is capable to generate an access token for you. The solution is to make your model public. It's not recommended, but for a limited period of time, and for test only, why not!

For this, grant `allUsers` with the role `roles/ml.modelUser` on your model.

---

**EDIT 1**

I didn't find how to do this on a model with the console. I did t before but there were some updates... Very strange. I achieve this with the gcloud CLI

```
gcloud ai-platform models add-iam-policy-binding --region=us-central1 --member=allUsers --role=roles/ml.modelUser test
```

Comment: Using the console, in my model's page, I see no option to grant roles. How can I grant `allUsers` with the role `roles/ml.modelUser` on my model using the console? @guillaume

Answer (score -3):

By following [Method: projects.predict](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/predict#http-request) documentation.

```
POST https://{endpoint}/v1/{name=projects/**}:predict
```

Comment: This is just the endpoint for the request, it doesn't show how to deal with authentication.